# Where should I be placing my reading condition in the Consumer-Producer problem?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

Suppose I have 2 kinds of producers, 1 produces data from reading a text file(set of even numbers), the other generates odd numbers using the rand() function.
Now I want 2 kinds of consumers who will consume data based on whether it was even or odd (produced by producer1 or producer2).
I used 2 semaphores (bufferEmpty,bufferFull) and a mutex buffer to synchronize all of this.
What I am failing to add is where do I:

1. apply the condition
2. stop the thread on its current execution of buffer
3. don't let any thread to skip my data
   Can anyone help?

I wrote this current code

```
void* producer1(void* args){
    fstream obj;
    cout<<"I will read data from OS_A2_Q1.txt"<<endl;
    obj.open("OS_A2_Q1.txt",ios::in);
    if (!obj){
        cout<<"Error opening file"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        int data;
        while (1) {
            obj >>data;
            //cout<<data<<endl;
            cout<<"I am producer 1"<<endl;
            sem_wait(&bufferEmpty);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexBuffer);               
            buffer[count] = data;
            count++;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexBuffer);
            sem_post(&bufferFull);
            if (obj.eof())
                break;
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout<<"I have successfully completed reading data from file"<<endl;
    }
    obj.close();
}
void* producer2(void* args){
    cout<<"I will insert 100 random numbers into the buffer"<<endl;
    int x,i=0;
    
    while (i < 100){
        while (1){
            x = rand() % 100;
            if ((x % 2 != 0) && (x != 0))
                break;
        }
        i++;
        cout<<"inside prod 2"<<endl;
        sem_wait(&bufferEmpty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexBuffer);               
        buffer[count] = x;
        count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexBuffer);
        sem_post(&bufferFull);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
void* consumer1(void* args){
    while (readcount < 200) {
        int y;
        // Remove from the buffer
        sem_wait(&bufferFull);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexBuffer);
        y = buffer[count - 1];
        readcount++;
        count--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexBuffer);
        sem_post(&bufferEmpty);

        // Consume
        if(y % 2 == 0){
            printf("\nI am Consumer 1\n");
            printf("\nGot %d\n", y);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
void* consumer2(void* args){
    while (readcount < 200) {
        int y;
        // Remove from the buffer
        sem_wait(&bufferFull);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexBuffer);
        y = buffer[count - 1];
        readcount++;
        count--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexBuffer);
        sem_post(&bufferEmpty);

        // Consume
        if(y % 2 != 0){
            printf("\nI am Consumer 2\n");
            printf("\nGot %d\n", y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but directly doing `x = 2 * (rand() % 50) + 1;` seems more succinct than a while-loop with repeated is-odd and is-non-zero checks. Just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you but this is just an assignment for my university

Comment: Your _current code_ is not C code.

Comment: It is impossible to say what you should do if you don't tell what you are to do, i. e. what the actual assignment is.